# Malicious Files - Backed Up To Local Machine Dangerous?

Tags: magento-1.9, backup

This may seem like a silly question, but our virtual dedicated server has been spammed (outgoing mail spam) and it appears that our server may have been compromised because the latest Magento updates haven't been done (bad, I know). I want to get Magento updates, but first I really wanted to create a backup of the files on our local server (i.e. computer) so that we have them to reference / fall back on as needed. My concern is that am I putting my computer at harm being that there are malicious files in there causing the spam? The last thing I want is a virus on the computer too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a possibility comprised server then putting that server on your computer will also make it possibility comprised. Best practice would be place a back-up somewhere isolated (VM etc.)

Comment: can you mark this answer with the checkmark?